# Red-Black tree Restructuring

Tags: red-black-tree

I really wonder that is there any change of Black node number from External node to Root node when restructuring processor is occur.

plz answer me.

( I really sorry about my English poor. )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems a better fit for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Stedy Thanks. I heard that site first time!